# PyQt5 Style Slides CSS

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqt6

[I am trying to make similar style slides using CSS for pyqt5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI5gY.png)

I am trying to make similar style slides using CSS for pyqt5 I tried making it in QTDesigner but I can't seem to do it correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. Please show us your attempts, so that we can tell you what was wrong in them. Also, ensure that you carefully read the QSS [syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html), [reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html) and [related examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider).

Comment: Well, I don't know how to start that's the thing. I can't show you anything. I need help.

Comment: Well, then I'm sorry but as already said StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. We answer to actual, practical programming questions. We already rarely answer to "How to do XYZ" questions, we certainly don't do it for "I don't know where to start". Sorry but these are the rules. If you did try something, then we'll help you, otherwise look for actual tutorials, and patiently study the documentation (starting with the above links).